# Need to make multiple async call to the same endpoint in Angular 8

Tags: angular, http, asynchronous, rxjs

I have a get call which accepts only one search number and returns the result. I have a requirement where I need to search with multiple numbers using the same `GET` call. I know it can be achieved by opening new endpoint with `POST` call but unfortunately I have to use the existing `GET` call.

I am going to loop the `array` and make a call for each number which I have in the multiple number list.

I want to know what is the best way to make a call for each number and as soon as result for one number is available update the UI instead of waiting for all calls to finish?

**here is my `GET` call**

```
searchNumbers(
    Request: string, type: string) {
    const requestOptions = {
      headers: this.headers
    };
    const url = `${environment.customerApiUrl.status}?${type.toLowerCase()}=${Request}`;  
    return this.httpClient.get(
        url, requestOptions );
  }
```

What is the best way to call this endpoint Asynchronously and updated the UI as soon as I receive the data for any particular number from the number list.

Comment: Do I understand correctly: So you want to loop an array of numbers, let's say [3, 4, 5] and make a get call for each of these numbers? Where do you want the results stored? push them in some sort of result array?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To accomplish this, you can use [`from`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/creation/from) to create an observable stream that emits each array element individually.  Then use [`mergeMap`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/mergemap) to map each value to your api call (*that returns observable*) and merge their output into the created stream:

```js
  searchMultipleNumbers(numbers: number[]) {
    return from(numbers).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.httpClient.get(`url/${id}`))
    );
  }
```

The output responses from the calls will be emitted individually as they come back.

Here's a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66448505?file=src/app/app.component.ts).

If you wanted to emit the full array off all results each time a response comes back, you could use [`scan`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/transformation/scan) to emit an array of all emissions.

```js
  searchMultipleNumbers(numbers: number[]) {
    return from(numbers).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.httpClient.get(`url/${id}`)),
      scan((all, val) => [...all, val], [])
    );
  }
```

([StackBlitz #2](https://stackblitz.com/edit/so-66448505-b?file=src/app/app.component.ts))

To catch and ignore Errors, you can use [`catchError`](https://www.learnrxjs.io/learn-rxjs/operators/error_handling/catch) and just return [`EMPTY`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/empty):

```js
  searchMultipleNumbers(numbers: number[]) {
    return from(numbers).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.httpClient.get(`url/${id}`).pipe(catchError(()=>EMPTY))
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for this solution. I have just one more question that here you directly use a fake `httpClient`. Can you tell me how to call the function from a service.

something like 

`searchMultipleNumbers(numbers: number[]) {
    return from(numbers).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.myService.searchFunction(id))
    );
  }`

Comment: getting error 

`error TS2345: Argument of type '(id: string) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: string, index: number) => ObservableInput<{}>'.
  Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<{}>'.`

Comment: can I move this to the service call where I am making the http request.

` return from(numbers).pipe(
      mergeMap(id => this.httpClient.get(`url/${id}`))
    );`

Comment: Never mind I made it working. Thanks for your help.

Comment: I got the code working but there is one issue. If any request from the array fails then all other requests stops working ... For example if I get a 404 for one particular number from the requested number array then all pending requests stops working ...

Comment: You can use `catchError` on the http call and return `EMPTY` to swallow errors.  I updated the SB and the answer above

Comment: I need to get the error object to show the error for particular failed request on the UI. what that work ?

Comment: `catchError` receives the error, so instead of ignoring it, you can use it like `catchError(err => { // do something here }`

Comment: as we are returning observable, returning anything in the catchError block will cause this error 
`Argument of type '(error: any) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(err: any, caught: Observable<string>) => ObservableInput<any>'.
Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'ObservableInput<any>'.`

Comment: is there a way to capture errors for each failed request where we are subscribing ?

Comment: Post a new question for that. :-)